# Asking for feedback on the application of a Central Limit Theorem

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem, dependent-variable

Let $\{X_{n,i}:1\leq i \leq d_n\}$ be a triangular array of mean zero random variables where $d_n$ is a positive increasing sequence ($d_n\leq n$). Under some conditions, a Central Limit Theorem states that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{d_n}X_{n,i}\overset{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2).$$
where $\lim_{n\to\infty}Var\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{d_n}X_{n,i}\bigg)=\sigma^2$
**Problem**

In my case, I'm working with the sum $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i\in J_n}X_{n,i}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_{n,i}1_{i\in J_n}$ where the cardinality of the set $J_n$ is $d_n$. $J_n$ is a set of consecutive indices. The difference from the above sum in the Theorem  is that the smallest index of each $J_n$ does not need to be $1$. Also, for small $n$, say for all $n<n_0$, $J_n$ is empty, this means $d_n=0$.  Although the sum I'm working on is not exactly the same of that of in the Theorem, it is intuitive that the weak convergence also holds. I believe this is a matter of defining the triangular array properly.

Consider the triangular array $\{X_{n,i}:i\in J_n, n\geq 1\}$. To apply the above theorem, I'm thinking of bring the indices in $J_n$ to the initial portion of each line of the triangle array. Like this:
[image]

My question is, if I show that 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{d_n}Z_{n,i}\overset{d}{\to} N\bigg(0,\sigma^2_1 \bigg),$$
does
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i\in J_n}X_{n,i}\overset{d}{\to} N\bigg(0,\sigma^2_1 \bigg),$$
also holds?

*Note that $\lim Var\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i=1}^{d_n}Z_{n,i}\bigg)=\lim Var\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d_n}}\sum_{i\in J_n}X_{n,i}\bigg)=\sigma^2_1$

*The refeered result is the [Theorem A.1 of Politis et al. (1997)](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-0000-00007cdb20cb/joeOld.pdf), p. 305

Comment: This is just a trivial restriction to a sub-array. What you need to check if the assumptions of the theorem (Lindeberg or martingale-type conditions, or whatever) holds for a sub-array,

Comment: @Michael exactly!  I showed that the conditions hold for the sub-array (moment and mixing conditions).

Comment: The right hand side of your limit expressions should not depend on n. In your quoted result, it's not immediate that condition A.8 passes to sub-arrays.

Comment: You are right. My bad. It is actually the limit of that variance! I will fix it

Comment: About your comment on A.8, I will use Ekstrom's CLT. He stablished the same CLT as Politis, without condition A.8. If I assume only the existence of $\sigma^2_1$ above, it would be suficient to show the weak convergence. But this is another subject nd require the concept of weakly approaching in distribution. I was manly worried about the applicability of this CLT for sub-triangle arrays.

Comment: I noticed that the sum $d_n^{1/2}\sum_{i=1}^{d_n}x_{n,i}$ is associated with many distinct triangular arrays, if one interchanges the positions of the zeros. I believe I can choose any of them and apply the CLT (if the conditions of the theorem are satisfied).